I got an unknown voltage error. How can I fix it?



I got an unknown voltage error. How can I fix it?

is it case sensitive?

@Neil_UK LTspice net names aren't case sensitive. If you use uppercase in one it will show it that way on the schematic, but any references LTspice itself makes to it such as at the top of the waveform viewer or log files it will be shown as lowercase.

Same problem as your previous question (I want to write v(x+)/v(vin) instead of v(x+). how will I do?), you have shorted Vin to ground. Vin stopes becoming a node name and GND wins over it.

What should not be done to avoid a short circuit?

Don't introduce the ground there? Put a voltage source between Vin and ground?

I can see two possible problems:

There are two different names allocated to the same node, and
Node name "V+" does not exist.  Did you mean "VP"?



yes I meant vp.
